# Calculating For Sub-Total and Grand-Total -JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i check a checkbox, it displays the price of the item selected. Now when i click on the button increment or decrement, it multiplies the quantity against the price.

Now with my code, what happens is, when i check two items, `cup and plates`, the increment and decrement button for the first item skips 2 to 3 and it also controls the sub total for the second item as well.

Why is this happening?

```js
function calc(product) {

  item = JSON.parse(product.dataset.product);

  if (product.checked == true) {
    $('.panel').append(
      '<p  class="price" data-price="' + product.price + '">' + product.price + '</p>' +
      '<p class="subtotal" ><span></span></p>' +
      '<div class="sp-quantity">' +
      '<div class="sp-minus fff"> <a class="ddd" href="#">-</a>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="sp-input">' +
      '<input type="text" class="quantity-input" value="1">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="sp-plus fff"> <a class="ddd" href="#">+</a>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
    )

    $(".ddd").on("click", function() {

      var $button = $(this),
        $input = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quantity-input");
      var oldValue = $input.val(),
        newVal;

      if ($.trim($button.text()) == "+") {

        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
      } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 0) {
          newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
          newVal = 0;
        }
      }

      $input.val(newVal);
      var grandTotal = 0;
      var product;

      $('.panel .container').each(function() {
        product = $(this),
          quantity = newVal,
          price = Number(product.find('.price').data('price')),
          points = Number(product.find('.points').data('points')),
          total = quantity * price; //

        product.find('.subtotal span').text(total);
        grandTotal += total;

      });

      $('.checkout span').text(grandTotal);

    });

  } else {
    var total = $(".panel .container [data-id=" + product.id + "]").parent().find(".subtotal").text();
    $(".panel .container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]").parent().remove();

    if (total) {
      $('.checkout span').text(function(index, oldtext) {
        alert(oldtext);
        console.log('this is my old text ' + oldtext)
        return oldtext ? oldtext - total : oldtext;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**update**

```js
product = $('.panel .container');
quantity = newVal;
price = Number(product.find('.price').data('price'));
points = Number(product.find('.points').data('points'));
total = quantity * price; //

alert(newVal);
```

Comment: Try declaring `var product` within the ` $('.panel .container').each(function() {....`var product...` block instead of declaring it outside of block

Comment: @zer00ne, i just did and it is still the same

Comment: Post an example of  `product`.

Comment: @zer00ne please look at the update

Comment: the increment and decrement button for one item is controlling the sub-total for all other items

Comment: the increment and decrement button for one item is controlling the sub-total for all other items

Comment: The `product` is a JSON dataset that's passed thru `calc(product)` then later on there's new variable declared as `var product` and `this`. As far as I can tell both `product` variables are within the same scope.

Comment: @zer00ne,  so you mean i should use a new variable ? changing the variable doesn't change anything either

Comment: Yeah, it's worth a shot. Or eliminate the second `product` since it's only a reference to `$(this)`. If you need to reference `this` you can use `$(obj)[0].bind(this)` or `$(obj)[0].call(this)`

Comment: I am not getting your explanation actually

Comment: Declare `var oldValue` outside of `click` event handler, or declare `oldValue` with `let`.

Comment: Is there a reason for: `product = $(this)` ?

Comment: @zer00ne i use that to reach the panel. Now when i `alert(price)` after the button is clicked, the price of the both selected items pops up 2 times for each items. Does it give you a hint

Comment: Looks to me like you might have an extra </div> - I can count 5 against 4 opening tags. That would tend to screw up your DOM and cause stuff like this.....

Comment: @james-geldart, I just verified. there's no extra </div> in my code. i will edit this

Comment: @XamarinDevil `$input.val(newVal);` is reassigned?

Comment: @zer00ne, yes it is reassigned. when i console, i see that it is reassigned

Comment: the default state for newVal is 1. when i alert newVal, it gives 2 , 2 , 3. I can't tell where this is from but instead it has to give, 2, 1 since i only clicked on `+` for `cups`

Comment: OK, then don't do this: `$('.panel .container').each(function() {
        product = $(this),
          quantity = newVal,...` That looks like the `newVal` is being used on each `.panel` which is 3 times per click

Comment: look at my update. now when i alert newVal, it gives 2,3 instead of 2,1 since i clicked on `+` for `cups`. Now, the quantity (newVal) doesn't stay at 2, it goes to 3

Comment: I got to get back to work, good luck, sir.